# Python All my keys are using the same values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with my code! I am in the process of making a program that will create a file that will store words alongside thee definitions using dictionaries. So far, I have gotten it to work the way I intended, but when I see the results, each key that returns all have the same value. Why/

```
words = {}

word = raw_input("What word is it? ")
definition = raw_input("What's the meaning of the word ")
words[word] = definition

addition = raw_input('Have another word you need to remember? Y/N ')

while addition == "Y":
    word = raw_input("What word is it? ")
    definition = raw_input("What's the meaning of the word ")
    words[word] = definition
    addition = raw_input('Have another word you need to rememeber? Y/N ')

# How to get my key to display the correct information.

for key, value in words.items():
    print(key + ": " + definition)


f = open("Dcitionary.txt", "w")

for key, value in words.items():
    f.write(key + ": " + definition)

f.close
```

Comment: Because you're printing `definition`, always the first one you input, not `value`. The dictionary is fine.

Comment: And today we learned the importance of using unique variable names

Comment: Side note, `f.close` does not close the file because you're justjust referencing the function name. You need `f.close()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here some improvement but if you introduce twice the same word it will overwrite the existing one:

```
dictionary_words={}

addition="Y"
while addition=="Y":
    word = raw_input("What word is it? ")
    definition = raw_input("What's the meaning of the word ")
    dictionary_words[word]=definition
    addition = raw_input('Have another word you need to rememeber? Y/N ')

print ("\n\n Key-Values\n")
for i in dictionary_words:
    print (i+" : "+dictionary_words[i])
```

you should improve a lot this code, for the condition that in this case stop for any character different from "Y"; then you should improve as well the chance to have a key with multiple values too....
but this is a small improvement plus it's printing

> key : values

Comment: Thanks for your help!